What would the intensity of overlapping spectral lines in emission spectroscopy be?
According to NIST, Helium has these spectral lines in air:
Intensity      Wavelength (Å)     Spectrum   Ref. 
  500    P      5875.6148         He I       M02
  250    P      5875.6404         He I       M02

I'm not sure which intensity scale they're using, but I guess that doesn't really matter.
Suppose I have an emission spectroscope and I am observing Helium, but my instrument's resolution is poor such that I cannot differentiate these two lines, and thus I only see one, broader line.
Would the intensity of this line be the brighter one (500), the lesser (250), the average (375), the sum (750), or something else?
I don't imagine that it would be less than 500 since that would seem to imply that it became harder to see this line with the addition of another fainter line, but perhaps I'm wrong.

There are actually three yellow lines: see my answer here here for the helium visible spectrum, as an echellogram, along with the NIST wavelengths. My spectrograph’s resolution is insufficient to resolve the three lines, so the result is a so-called ‘blend’. Each line independently contributes its intensity, so what you ‘see’ with the spectroscope or spectrograph depends on the resolving power of the instrument. In the case of the spectrograph used in my answer, the ‘blend’ pretty much looks like a single spectral line.

The 5876 line is a tripletP to tripletD line in the metastable helium triplet atom. These lines are three lines that are close in He. These lines become more distinct for atoms such as the alkaline earths and Zn, Cd, and Hg with well-shielded s2 configurations. This is explained in detail in Gerhard Hertzberg, Atomic Spectra and Atomic Structure, page 65 ff. This book and his books on diatomic and molecular compounds are excellent reads for one interested in spectroscopy, both an overview and on perusal of the details. [I believe he won a Nobel Prize for his work in spectroscopy.]
Close attention to the NIST data, knowing that there are three lines, answers your question. The first line at twice the intensity is two unresolved lines suggesting that the intensities added. This is complicated for line spectra because intensities are integrated over a wavelength range as a function of resolution.

If your instrument has a very, very wide slit width, say 10 nm, i.e. low resolution then you will observe all the lines at their total or summed intensity fully from about 586.5 to about 588.5 nm as a broad smear. If the resolution of your instrument is better than the line-width of the transitions, which could be limited by Doppler and collision broadening, then you will resolve individual peaks with their proper intensity and width. In general you will observe the convolution of the transition line-shape, however complicated that might be, with the slit function of your spectrograph.


I'm not sure which intensity scale they're using, but I guess that
doesn't really matter.

The intensity scale is arbitrary but this is the best NIST or anyone else can do. You assign a value of 1000 to the strongest line under the experimental conditions and scale the rest of the spectral lines with respect to that. So the numbers 500 and 250 show the relative scale. Consider "intensity" as the number of photons reaching the detector in a second per a given area.
Now coming to your question, what will be the intensity "value" in your lower resolution apparatus where these lines merge? Nobody can predict that single number without actually doing the experiment.
You will have to assign the strongest line, the same line that NIST used, a value of 1000, and then check these lines and measure the intensity, perhaps from a photograph. You can assign your own values. ImageJ is a great idea to play with if you like doing experiments with spectroscopy. I measured sodium wavelengths accurately at 589 nm from a cardboard apparatus a decade ago.
